# Search and replace Using NsRegularExpression

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsregularexpression

I am replacing a font which is in px in a string to another value. After, I replace the px in the string, I am passing it to UIWebView to display it. The problem is that after I change the px value, it has no effect.

The string contains HTML like this(for example):

```
<html><head><script> document.ontouchmove = function(event) { if (document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.clientHeight) event.preventDefault(); } </script><style type='text/css'>* { margin:0; padding:0; } p { color:black; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:26px; } a { color:#000000;}</style></head><body>Look at Google</body></html>
```

The code looks like this:

```
//Setting of WebSites Text
NSString *websitesHTML = [[websitesArray objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"Websites"];

//For iPad
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\d\\dpx;" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedWebsitesHTML = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:websitesHTML options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [websitesHTML length]) withTemplate:@"40px"];
NSLog(@"%@",modifiedWebsitesHTML);

UIWebView *websitesWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[websitesWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 160, 600, 300)];
websitesWebView.delegate = self;
[websitesWebView setOpaque:NO];
websitesWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[websitesWebView loadHTMLString:modifiedWebsitesHTML baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
[self.view addSubview:websitesWebView];
```

Any suggestion will be helpful... Need some guidance on this...

Comment: But if the substitution works, what does it have to do with the regular expression? Isn't it a problem with the web view or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your regular expression isn't matching because "26px" is not followed by a semi-colon in your HTML. Either add it in the HTML or remove it from the pattern.

*Edit:* The changed CSS doesn't have an effect because it's styling the `<p>` tag, but the `<body>` doesn't contain one.

Comment: Is that your actual HTML in the question? You're styling the `p` tag, but there is no `p` tag in your `body`...